# The difference between max.gap and window.size in seqeconstraint

Tags: r, traminer

I am having hard time understanding the difference between max.gap and window.size and how they work.

Let's say I have the following sequence: `947-(SP6)-992-(CP2)-2-(SP6)-4-(SP10)`, where the numbers between events indicate the minutes (4 minutes between SP6 and SP10).

With `max.gap=2` constraint, I get the following results (although I expected to have only `(CP2)-(SP6)` in the results because they have `-2-` between them):

```
> seqefsub(peer_data.seqe[30], min.support = 1, constraint = seqeconstraint(max.gap = 2))
         Subsequence Support Count
1              (CP2)       1     1
2        (CP2)-(SP6)       1     1
3 (CP2)-(SP6)-(SP10)       1     1
4             (SP10)       1     1
5              (SP6)       1     1
6       (SP6)-(SP10)       1     1
```

I do not understand why do I have `(SP6)-(SP10)` in the results. Here, how `window.size` would change the things? I appreciate if someone explain this clearly. I am using this for my research and I do not want to use it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `max.gap=k` condition means that we search for subsequences with at most *k* units of time between two successive events in the subsequence.

The `window.size=w` condition means that we search for subsequences with a duration between the first and last events that does not exceed *w*.

Thus `max.gap` refers to the time between successive events in the subsequence and `window.size` to the total duration of the subsequence.

I illustrate with your example sequence.

```
library(TraMineR)
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, text = "
  id timestamp event
  30 947 'sp6'
  30 1939 'cp2'
  30 1941 'sp6'
  30 1945 'sp10'
  ")

(eseq <- seqecreate(dat)  )
# [1] 947-(sp6)-992-(cp2)-2-(sp6)-4-(sp10)

seqefsub(eseq, min.support = 1, constraint = seqeconstraint(max.gap = 2))
#   Subsequence Support Count
# 1       (cp2)       1     1
# 2 (cp2)-(sp6)       1     1
# 3      (sp10)       1     1
# 4       (sp6)       1     1
#
# Computed on 1 event sequences
# Constraint Value
# max.gap     2
# count.method  COBJ
```

As you can see, with `max.gap=2` we get the subsequences with a single event and the subsequence `(cp2)-(sp6)` because `sp6` occurs 2 minutes after `cp2`. Any other subsequence would have at least a gap greater than 2 between two successive events. (This outcome does not correspond to yours, which let's me think that `peer_data.seqe[30]` is not the shown example sequence).

Now, using `window.size=6`, we get three more subsequences.

seqefsub(eseq, min.support = 1, constraint = seqeconstraint(window.size = 6))

```
#          Subsequence Support Count
# 1              (cp2)       1     1
# 2       (cp2)-(sp10)       1     1
# 3        (cp2)-(sp6)       1     1
# 4 (cp2)-(sp6)-(sp10)       1     1
# 5             (sp10)       1     1
# 6              (sp6)       1     1
# 7       (sp6)-(sp10)       1     1
# 
# Computed on 1 event sequences
# Constraint Value
# window.size     6
# count.method  COBJ
```

In particular `(cp2)-(sp6)-(sp10)` has a total duration of 6 and the total time between the two events of `(cp2)-(sp10)` is also 6. Reducing the window.size would eliminate these two sequences. Likewise, `(sp6)-(sp10)` would be eliminated with a window size smaller than 4.

As a last example, I combine `window.size=6` with `max.gap=4`.

```
seqefsub(eseq, min.support = 1, constraint = seqeconstraint(window.size = 6, max.gap=4))
#          Subsequence Support Count
# 1              (cp2)       1     1
# 2        (cp2)-(sp6)       1     1
# 3 (cp2)-(sp6)-(sp10)       1     1
# 4             (sp10)       1     1
# 5              (sp6)       1     1
# 6       (sp6)-(sp10)       1     1
#
# Computed on 1 event sequences
# Constraint Value
# max.gap     4
# window.size     6
# count.method  COBJ
```

We get here one subsequence less than in the previous example, namely `(cp2)-(sp10)` because there is a gap of 6 minutes between the two events.

Comment: Wow, great answer! It is impossible to find such detailed and clear explanations about TraMiner. One question: is it possible to include only consecutive actions? For example, in your second answer, I would want to exclude `(cp2)-(sp10)` since in between there is actually `sp6`. Is this possible? As far as I see it is not. I appreciate your help a lot!

Comment: What you want are actually substrings rather than subsequences. And you are right, currently TraMineR has no function to search for substrings of event sequences.